# Searchview magIcon comes out of nowhere

Tags: android, icons, searchview

I've add an expanded searchview to my search result page. When I touch to start typing a magicon comes out of nowhere! I made it just disappear in time something is typed and also it comes back when I press back button.

```
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            int magIconId = getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
            ImageView magIconImage = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(magIconId);
            magIconImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return true;
        }
```

the second Icon in the below pic:

[searchview magIcon pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lUsH.png)

[Want to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkjR1.png)

Comment: Please, define `magicon`.

Comment: @dergolem the gray search icon in the pic. I add a new picture to show what I want it to be

Comment: I see. You want to get rid of the `ghost` search icon.

Comment: Yes the image is there by default in `Holo` theme.

Comment: I use to only `return false;` in `onQueryTextChange()` and do the search in `onQueryTextSubmit()` in which, after searching, I also collapse the SearchView and `return true;`

Comment: by default it's 'return false;' and I changed the code it make it disapear like second pic. but I couldn't make it disapear always. it apears the moment I touch the 'searchview' and disapear when start to type and apears again when press back button!

Comment: I wonder why it doesn't happen to me (I'm using the support library, if it can help).